# How to obtain a web service from another server web service on same machine

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, iis

I have a Spring Rest web application and I want to invoke some json rest services from .net web application in IIS server. I used Jackson for rest. Is the any plugin or jar to invoke a web service from another server web service on same machine this task without getting connection URL and processing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's RestTemplate to call ReSTFul API like below.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
POJO obj = restTemplate.getForObject("http://apiserver:8080/api/pojo", POJO.class);
log.info(obj.toString());
```

For more information visit [official spring site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).